# Android Studio cannot find custom SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source, android-sdk-tools

I've added my SDK to Android Studio, but it doesn't appear in External Libraries, and gradle fails to sync.

Steps I followed:

- Created my SDK in my AOSP build tree
- In AS:

  - SDK Manager: I added my SDK as an SDK Update Site
  - SDK Platforms: Installed my SDK
  - Project Structure: Modules: Compile Sdk Version: I selected my SDK.  This modifies my `compileSdkVersion` in my build.gradle file.

At this point, gradle attempts to sync and failed.  The log shows:

```
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.issues.SdkPlatformNotFoundException: Module: 'mobile' platform 'MATT:MATT SDK Add-On LOCAL_BUILD:30' not found.
```

(mobile is the name of my module)

Thing is, everything appears correct.  I see the SDK installed exactly where I would expect it in my SDK directory.  As I mentioned above, the Project Structure dialog picks it up and writes it to the gradle file.  I'm invalidated my cache, restarted, re-tried everything, everything I can think of.  The name of the `compileSdkVersion` appears to be exactly what the XML dictates it should be (and it was all loaded by AS, I didn't manually type it)

I also do not see my SDK in the External Libraries tree in the Project's View

My AS version is

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 14
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7260174, built on April 5, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+0-b77-7246554 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.8.0-44-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 28
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin
Current Desktop: i3
```

Though I had a co-worker who was previously able to set this up also run into this issue.  I suspect there's some subtle step we're missing.

Other settings:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'MATT:MATT SDK Add-On LOCAL_BUILD:30'
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.1'
    // ...
}
```

I've played with other installed `buildToolsVersion` versions to no avail.

Comment: I have that as far as I know, in my SDK Update Sites, I added my XML file, with this I was then able to successfully install the SDK in the SDK Platforms tab.  I'm just unable to use this is any way.

Comment: Using sdk add on requires you adding the repository in SDK manager which will have your stubbed jar and xml definition for the SDK add-on. Also adding uses library in your manifest, that matches what the XML definition states. Been ages since I did this but from memory there's quite a bit of ceremony involved .. Ended up just creating a reflection library that just links at runtime to get around all this cruft

Comment: Also from memory upper and lower case SDK add-on naming important, especially on case sensitive OS.

Comment: My goal is to be able build against my (stubbed) SDK in Android Studio.  I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting?  In any case, the case matches perfectly (and also it was populated by AS, not by me.)  I also setup `uses-library` in my manifest, it doesn't seem to do anything yet though

Comment: If you have added the repository, appeared in available sdks, selected it in SDK manager, added this to your gradle file, added to uses-library to your manifest .. Then I'm out of immediate ideas.  I meant that this stubbed jar resolves at runtime against your custom aosp build. There is nothing to stop you invoking this via reflection without the need of the actual SDK add-on directly.

Comment: So if my `uses-library` tag in the manifest is wrong, that could be leading to `SdkPlatformNotFoundException` error?  Even though when I switch the `compileSdkVersion 30` it all builds.  What do you mean by using this _via_ reflations?  I'm not a Java dev, I'm much more comfortable at the Android native layer. :)

Comment: Seriously SDK level is child's play compared to native level! If I can find the config later I'll post an update.  Reflection I'm Java is the ability to inspect classes and objects at runtime I.e access to private variables, create objects simply by namespace, kind of an anti pattern .. But can work in edge cases.